# HelloWorld style DataGrid had blank rows as result

Tags: wpf, datagrid

xaml side:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

I tried also with:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyObj}" />
```

The code behind:

```
MyGrid.ItemsSource = new[] {
    new MyObj{A = "aaa", B = "sss"},
    new CompteurDate{A = "bbb", B = "eee"}
};
```

The result shows the correct number of items in the grid, but the rows are blank.
Im sure it's deadly easy but Im stuck :-/
Any idea?

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Rachel, I didn't post properly:

```
MyGrid.ItemsSource = new[] {
    new MyObj{A = "aaa", B = "sss"},
    new CompteurDate{A = "bbb", B = "eee"}
};
```

Should have been:

```
MyGrid.ItemsSource = new[] {
    new MyObj{A = "aaa", B = "sss"},
    new MyObj{A = "bbb", B = "eee"}
};
```

Sorry about that.. (I a

Anyway, I found my way! The object kind I was using was in cause. Whit this it didn't work:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string A;
    public string B;
}
```

And like that it did:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

So I step out of my hello world code, back to my real life implemantation, and.... it didn't work, damn.
I had an IEnumerable instead of an array. Long story short, adding a "ToArray()" at the end made it, but I don't understand why. Ok, my enumerable was subject to late execution, but the datagrid reading its ItemsSource shoud have trigged this execution, isn't it?

So, problem solved but if someone have some rational light to put on this magic...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do here, but there are a few things I see which could be causing the problem

By default, DataGrids auto-generate their columns based on the properties on the objects that are in the `ItemsSource`. The problem is, you have two different objects in your `ItemsSource`, so it doesn't know which object to use the properties from. I can't even reproduce your error using the code-behind you provided because it tells me "No best type found for implicitly-typed array", although if I specify the `ItemsSource` is an `object` array, then I get the results you're describing.

The 2nd part confusing me is you are setting your `ItemsSource` in both the XAML and the code-behind. You only need to set it once.

Now you could set the `DataGrid.DataContext` in the code-behind to an object, then bind the `ItemsSource` in the XAML to a property on that exists on that object, so perhaps that's what you're trying to do.